# Application.yml ignored by microservice which is a config service, how to fix that

Tags: spring, spring-boot, config

I have a microservice which is basically a config service in which there are some properties like server port 8050 and spring active profile given. But this is not read and microservice is starting on 8888 automatically when it's run, what can be the cause of it?

I have tried passing port in vm arugemtns while running but its not a fix actually. Because there is active profile also which is mentioned in yml file, it should be also read.

Comment: Hello, please add more details to the question. 1. What is the name of the property file in use? 2. What is the content of the file (paste it as code)? 3. What is the console log on application start?.

Comment: Yes..property file name is application.yml, content has only server.port as 8050 and spring active profile as native..in console logs it's saying no active profile set falling back to default and tomcat starting on 8888 instead of 8050

Comment: That's a prompt answer :) OK. The issue will be the name of the file. As you a calling the application with a profile 'native' then the name should be application-native.yml In VM arguments put -Dspring.profiles.active=native

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.